# $n^{th}$ derivative of $( 1+ x^2)^{(n-p+\frac{1}{2})}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I find 
 $$\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(( 1+ x^2)^{(n-p+\frac{1}{2})}\right)$$

Comment: Plug it into [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?js=off&i=n-th+derivative+of+(1%2Bx%5E2)%5E(n-p%2B1%2F2))?

Comment: What is $p$ a constant integer? I guess this is interms of hyper geometric series. Can you tell me where did you found this ?